# Acquiring instance of Background Service

Tags: android, service, background, instance

So i have a background service running. Now, if the user quits the activity, the service will still be running, right?
Now when user restarts the app, I want to access the background service and call some methods. How can I access the instance of the background service ?

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me out of the box!However do not use it if you have alternatives because public static members are not good unless they are final.
You can create a static variable with public scope in the Service.

```
public static BackgroundService bs;
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    bs=this;}
```

Then initialize the variable with 'this' which makes it a reference to the current running service. Use it as a reference in your activity anytime.

Comment: sounds great! will give it a try today and see if it works! thank you!

Comment: Ok, so i did what u said, but I am getting NullPointerException. My codes: http://pastebin.com/UT9Rcyi4

Comment: This is because as per (stackoverflow.com/questions/5085190/…) calls to the startService are asynchronous.So your service is not started yet!Just start your service in some other activity and from there start your activity using startActivity().It is working for me.

Comment: I used this but send local broadcast from service's 'onCreate' back to Activity > Activity then can get no null reference to 'MyService' using `MyService.getInstance()`

Comment: Good practice also to free this reference (set it to null) on service's onDestroy.

Comment: Thank you so much, when your activity exit, all static class will be GC, except the background running service. your answered inspired me.

Answer (score 1):

If the service continues to run after you quit your activity depends on how you start it. (Read about this in the documentation startService() / bindService())
If your Service is still running, then calls to startService()/bindService() will connect you to your 'old' service.

Comment: so you mean if the service is running in the background, a start or bind service will not yield a new instance of the service. Instead, will fetch the old one ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate with the background service. You can't use the binder mechanism, and about this you could access this web :[android develop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html.)

there is a example to tell to how to use the background service

thanks a lot